# More control for map editing in DOOM?

Tags: doom-2016

I'm a game-software developer with a lot of experience. When I heard we'll be given snap-map for DOOM I was so happy that I would be able to, basically, make my own campaign. I was imagining something like a Blizzard map editor for Warcraft 3 or StarCraft II.

Snap-map is pretty underwhelming:

- Very few types of rooms available
- Couldn't find how to make your own layout
- Couldn't find how to add your own monsters
- Don't see any possibility of adding/tweaking weapons & items

I wonder if I've just missed it, but can we go into more detail? Can we add custom scripts instead of dealing with drag'n'drop interface? Can we add custom sounds for dialogs etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, as SnapMap is available on XBOne/PS4, and MS/Sony don t want unknown code running on their machine and allowing the possibility of cracking the console, their is no way to use some scripting languages as in WarCraft III/StarCraft II.

However, the drag and drop system allow for almost everything in the map, even if it is not really pratical.

In the drag and drop element, you can find a lot of event to do conditionals test, logical operations, and play with the HUD, player's equipment, spawn rate...

Some peoples have started to make DOOM copy of other game or genre, like:

- Harvest DOOM: Harvest Moon recreation in DOOM, complete with crops grow and story.
- Silent Doom: Hooror game in the vein of Slenderman.

For a more complete list of thoses kind of map, who can all be edited again in SnapMap if you want to learn how they did it, I can recommand this [Rock Paper Shotgun article](https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2016/05/24/best-doom-snapmaps/), which made a "best of" of custom maps, or to search SnapMap for differents tag.